# SignalR - How to send message to everyone except caller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an Aspnet core 3.1 MVC application where I have configured a SignalR hub.

I have a controller where I go through dependency injection o `IHubContext`.

```
private readonly IHubContext<MesHub> _hubContext;
```

In my `MesHub` class, I have a connection method.

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (name == null)
            name = "Service";

        Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

I already turned off the method and principle works super well.

To send a message to all users who are logged into the hub, I use the following code.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("AtualizaCardOP","message 1");
```

But what I'm trying to do now is send another message to every user except the one who made the request. I tried many ways but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I couldn't help noticing that there are AllExcept and GroupExcept methods inside _hubContext.Clients... but the amazing thing is that I can't get them to work.

Examples tried and not working:

```
string idUserSignalR = this.User.Identity.Name;
await _hubContext.Clients.AllExcept(idUserSignalR).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");

await _hubContext.Clients.GroupExcept(idUserSignalR, idUserSignalR).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");
```

Here is an image that I didn't understand how to make it work due to the second parameter.

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Is there a way to do what I want?

**EDIT**

**The idUserSignalR is group name.**

if i use it code, only one group receive my message, but if use GroupExcept, all groups receive my message.

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Group(idUserSignalR).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE-2023-04-03

[image]

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<Users> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubcontext;

    public UsersController(SignInManager<Users> signInManager, ILogger<UsersController> logger, IHubContext<MainHub> hubcontext)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _hubcontext = hubcontext;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult testhub(string user,string message,string ConnectionId)
    {
        List<string> Except_connectionIds = new List<string>();
        Except_connectionIds.Add(ConnectionId);

        try
        {
            _hubcontext.Clients.AllExcept(Except_connectionIds).SendAsync("Chat_ReceiveMessage", user , DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+" " + message);
            return Ok("Send success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok("Send failed "+ ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
       
       
    }
```

#### UPDATE

**My Test Code**

```
    public async Task Chat_SendMessageToAll(string user, string message)
    {

        List<string> Except_connectionIds = new List<string>();
        Except_connectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        await Clients.AllExcept(Except_connectionIds).SendAsync("Chat_ReceiveMessage", user, message);

    }
```

**My Test Result**

[image]

#### PREVIOUS

---

```
List<string> Except_connectionIds  = new List<string>();
Except_connectionIds.Add(Context.ConnectionId); 

await _hubContext.Clients.GroupExcept(idUserSignalR,Except_connectionIds).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");
```

---

The correct usage should like below for [GroupExcept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.groupexcept?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [AllExcept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.allexcept?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

```
// Add idUserSignalR into List<String>
string idUserSignalR = this.User.Identity.Name;
// Add below
List<string> idUserSignalR_List  = new List<string>();
idUserSignalR_List.Add(idUserSignalR);  
public IReadOnlyList<string> readOnlyData = idUserSignalR_List.AsReadOnly();

await _hubContext.Clients.AllExcept(readOnlyData).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");

await _hubContext.Clients.GroupExcept("group_Name", readOnlyData).SendAsync("AtualizaPosicaoCardOP", "Mensagem aqui");
```

Comment: Hello, it dont work, idUserSignalR  is my group name and i try use it to AllExcept and GroupExcept but all received my message.

Comment: Hi @Renan, I misunderstanding the `idUserSignalR `.  We should add connectionid into `List<string> idUserSignalR_List`.

Comment: @Renan Then it should works well. You can check the official link in my answer.

Comment: i edit my question whit news data.

Comment: I dont know get idUserSignalR_List because i dont have this data in controller, how can i get it?

Comment: Hi @Renan, I have updated the answer, you can hard code here for test. It's just that the passed parameter type is wrong, please read the parameter definition of the method in the official document carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252745/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-renan).

Comment: Hello, can you share your controller code or github code?

Comment: will do next monday @Renan

Comment: Hi @Renan The method not inside the controller, it insides the Hub class.

Comment: so, it is the problem, i need to do it in my controller.

Comment: @Renan As you can see in my gif, I copy the connectionId and paste it in my testmethod in controller, and other page can received the message, and the tab which I copied the connectionId not received the message. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Nice. But how do you set your connectionId? in your OnConnectedAsync() in hub class? show me.

Comment: Hi @Renan, If you want the `connectionId`, you can manage the connectionId inside OnConnectedAsync method, for example, you want send message to `Jason`, then you can find all the connectionIds by userid, and paste it as param, like my sample.

Comment: @Renan And I believe this is another story, you can create a new post for your new question.